# In UNIX what "cat file1 > file1 does?"

Tags: redirect, unix

When the output of a command is redirected to a file, the output file is created or truncated by the shell before the command is executed, any idea what cat foo > foo does?

Comment: I suspect this would be a very good test of the behavior of the shell.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In all cases, the file is truncated. That’s because redirection is handled by the shell, which opens the file for writing before invoking the command.

```
cat foo > foo
```

The shell truncates and opens foo for writing, sets stdout to the file, and then exec’s `["cat", "foo"]`.

GNU cat is smart and refuses to redirect a file to itself. It does this by checking the device/inode pair on the input and output file descriptors; you can read the wonderful low-level details in [src/cat.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/cat.c#n706). It prints a message and quits.

BSD cat doesn’t have such a safety, but since the file has already been truncated, there is nothing to read, nothing to write, and it will halt.

---

You can spice things up a bit by appending instead of truncating.

```
echo hello > foo
cat foo >> foo
```

Now everything is the same except the shell opens the file for appending instead of truncating it.

GNU cat sees what you’re doing and stops; the file is untouched.

BSD cat goes into a loop and appends the file to itself until your disk fills up.

Comment: And that's why Mac is built on BSD.

Answer (score 4):

On Fedora 13 this is what I see

```
cat foo > foo
cat: foo: input file is output file
```

If `foo` contained anything previously, it is gone.

Answer (score 2):

The file is truncated first and then read, so this command would truncate the file.

When I tried to execute it I got this warning:

> cat: test.txt: input file is output file

Comment: What platform's `cat` do you have? `cat foo > foo` results in an empty `foo` file for me.

Answer (score 1):

Shell will truncate, `cat` apparently checks a named parm, but will not check against `stdin` as below and always succeeds:

```
$ uname -a
Linux bar 2.6.18-164.15.1.el5PAE #1 SMP Wed Mar 17 12:14:29 EDT 2010 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=foo bs=1024 count=4
4+0 records in
4+0 records out
4096 bytes (4.1 kB) copied, 0.00334456 seconds, 1.2 MB/s
$ od -c foo |head -2
0000000   U 371 003   z 224 334   z   K 236 221   k       <   c 256   !
0000020   %   % 256   V   \ 005   , 254   X 202 330 004 222   " 037 226
$ cat <foo >foo && od -c foo
0000000
```

Comment: Thanks for all of your replies. they were every helpful.